# Does PHP support array destructuring?

Tags: php

I mean something like this:

```
$arr = ["1", "2", "3"];

$one;
$two;
$three;

$new = [$one, $two, $three] = $arr;
```

As result I should get:

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$three = 3;
```

I tried, it works in PHP 7.3.2:

```
var_dump($one); // returns 1
```

Comment: If you try it that is what you'll get FWIW :)

Comment: kinda.. but using [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) or [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) functons

Comment: So it seems, https://3v4l.org/qGTAE >= php 7.1.0

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: https://3v4l.org/BAchH

Comment: I was already going to ask myself why I simulated the test and it worked, taking advantage, what would be its use?

Comment: do you really need to declare $one; $two; $three; first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, it is listed as a [new feature in PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring):

> The shorthand array syntax (`[]`) may now be used to destructure arrays for assignments (including within `foreach`), as an alternative to the existing `list()` syntax, which is still supported.

Comment: The new shorthand also supports destructuring arrays with string keys by key rather than by order, a very nice addition.